# Unity C# Input for continuous events?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Having some major trouble trying to use the updated Unity Input system, specifically with the Hold interaction. I'd like to continuously run code the code only during the performed phase, and have it do so continuously until the key being pressed is let up. Something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInputActions playerInputActions;
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
        playerInputActions.Player.Forward.performed += Forward;
        playerInputActions.Enable();
    }
    void onEnable() {
        playerInputActions.Enable();
    }
    void onDisable() {
        playerInputActions.Disable();
    }
    
    public void Forward(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
        while (context.performed) {
            Debug.Log("Hello");
            if (context.canceled) {
            break;}}
    }}
```

How do I reprogram this in order to function as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInputActions playerInputActions;


    private bool buttonPressed;
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
        playerInputActions.Player.Forward.performed += holdCallback;
        playerInputActions.Player.Forward.canceled += releaseCallback;
        playerInputActions.Enable();
        buttonPressed = false;
    }
    void onEnable() {
        playerInputActions.Enable();
    }
    void onDisable() {
        playerInputActions.Disable();
    }
    
    void Update(){
        if(buttonPressed)
            Forward();
    }

    void holdCallback(InputAction.CallbackContext context){
        buttonPressed = true;
    }
    
    void releaseCallback(InputAction.CallbackContext context){
        buttonPressed = false;
    }

    void Forward() {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```